# Filter for multiple values in a column in mat-filter

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to filter a column in an Angular Material table for multiple values.

[image: This is what my table looks like]

I have added two filters on this. A dropdown filter for position with checkboxes corresponding to each position and a text based filter for the name. I want the filter to work in such a way that if I click the checkbox for 1 and 10 in the position dropdown, both the rows are visible. But, if I write H in the name filter when those 2 checkboxes are ticked, only row 1 is visible. Basically, an OR in the multiple filters of one column and an AND between the filters of different columns.

Right now, my code works for the AND part between the two separate filters. However, if I select two checkboxes in the position dropdown menu, neither column is visible.

[Attaching my code on Stackblitz for reference](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbakxo-rueaim?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have changed some codes in `customFilterPredicate`

```
customFilterPredicate() {
    return (data: PeriodicElement, filter: string): boolean => {
      let searchString = JSON.parse(filter) as MyFilter;
      let isPositionAvailable = false;
      if (searchString.position.length) {
        for (const d of searchString.position) {
          // equal validate
          if (data.position.toString().trim() == d) {
          // OR
          // Checking index of
          if (data.position.toString().trim().indexOf(d) !== -1) {
            isPositionAvailable = true;
          }
        }
      } else {
        isPositionAvailable = true;
      }
      return isPositionAvailable && data.name.toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.name.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    }
  }
```

Add some interface for better typing

```
export interface MyFilter {
  position: string[],
  name: string,
  weight: string,
  symbol: string
}
```

Also add interface in `filteredValues`

```
filteredValues: MyFilter = { position: [], name: '', weight: '', symbol: '' };
```

Comment: Thanks! This works just as I wanted. I just noticed that when I click the checkbox for position 1, poistion 10's row is also visible because of the partial matching of the string. Do you know how I can make it match to the exact string instead of partial string?

Comment: instead of checking indefOf, check whether the value is equal or not. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter the data yourself and set the `data` of `dataSource`. Like following code.

Method for filtering the options.

```
filterOptions(positionValue: string[], nameValue: string): PeriodicElement[] {
  if ((!positionValue || positionValue.length === 0)  && !nameValue) {
    return ELEMENT_DATA;
  }
  const filtered = ELEMENT_DATA.filter((periodicElement) => {
    return (nameValue? periodicElement.name.toLowerCase().includes(nameValue.toLowerCase()): false) 
           || (positionValue ? positionValue.indexOf(periodicElement.position+'') !==-1: false)});
      return filtered;
}
```

You can use this on both filter change like following

```
this.positionFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((positionFilterValue)        => {
 this.dataSource.data = this.filterOptions(positionFilterValue, this.nameFilter.value);
});

this.nameFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((nameFilterValue) => {
  this.dataSource.data = this.filterOptions(this.positionFilter.value, nameFilterValue);
});
```

Here is your updated code with above changes https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbakxo-e4njon